# How can I remove the site logo?

Tags: 8

I want to remove the logo from my site.

I found some instructions on [Disabling the Drupal logo in your Drupal 8 theme](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-8/themes/toggle-logo). My problem is that the instructions say to unselect *Logo* in the toggle section of the theme settings page. I only get four options: *User pictures in posts*, *User pictures in comments*, *User verification status in comments*, and *Shortcut icon*.

I've checked in two sites. One has the vanilla Bartik theme, and the other has a subtheme of Bartik with no changes other than CSS.

How can I remove the logo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck the *Use the default logo supplied by the theme* option you find under the *Logo image settings* section. Don't forget to clear the cache.

Comment: In the screen shot on the page linked above, there are a whole lot of toggle options that I'm not seeing. How does one remove the site name or slogan now?

Comment: The tutorial posted in 2013, things changed since then. For site name or slogan, please open new post, I would be happy to answer them :D